# iOS Obj-C Equivalent to JavaScript's toString(16)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, math, random

I am trying to generate a hex id string from a random number. In JavaScript I do:

`var id = (
    Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 17) +
    Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 17) +
    Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 17) +
    Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 17)
).toString(16);`

The result is a random id like: "2d50e9b4835d7e0".

Is anyone aware of a similar method in iOS that I could use to do the same thing? I'd like the result of the iOS call to return a string of the same length (15 chars).

Answer (score 0):

You can get random number in Objective C using following code

```
-(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from to:(int)to {

    return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
}
```

**Edit** I have changed this method in order to get hex string

```
- (NSString *)getHexString
{   
    NSString *longlongstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d%d%d%d%d",[self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999],[self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999],[self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999],[self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999],[self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999],[self getRandomNumberBetween:100 to:999]];
    long long longnumber = [longlongstr longLongValue];
    NSString *hexStr =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llx",longnumber];
    NSLog(@"%@",hexStr);
     return hexStr;

}
```

So your code would look something like

```
NSString *hexStr = [self getHexString];
```

You can modify it as per your needs it gives you 15 digit hexa decimal value

Comment: The output from this does not appear to generate anything with letters in it, only a number represented as a string. Here is one example after run: @"31333832".

Comment: Sorry for that, i modified my answer , Please check and let me know if it works

Comment: Hmm, that definitely adds a few more alpha-characters but not many, and every number generated seems to end with a few zeros too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this:

```
#define cPow pow(3, 19)

long long val = ((
    rand() * cPow +
    rand() * cPow +
    rand() * cPow +
    rand() * cPow
));

NSString *newId = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%llx", val];
```